# Passthrough e-cig (without battery)

Tags: switches, circuit-design, cables

I'm looking to build myself a passthrough e-cigarette and here is the schematic I came up with :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGyamR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is will this work ? I mean in theory I think it should but is there practical things I'm missing ? I remember in school I saw that switches can do crazy things when pressed, would a step down voltage regulator be able to handle being connected directly to a button ? Is a Cinch cable suitable for such electrical values (less than 5v coming out of the buck converter and 1.8Ohm of resistance for the heating resistance).

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Comment: well, in principle, that works, but please be happy that  your wall adapter doesn't work like that (you'd be dead, likely).

Comment: Hey, I was thinking it's a plus - a faster way to get to the smoker's end goal, incurring less medical costs to society.

Comment: @MarcusMüller haha yeah I didn't find a correct picture for the wall adaptater but you get the point, it's a basic 220V AC to 9v DC converter.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is it bad dark humor or am I missing something here ? Thanks pal.

Comment: The schematic says 9V1A so, 9W. But 5V across 1.8 ohms = 25/1.8=14W, so, no, at 5V out of the buck converter, you'll need more than 1A from the wall adapter.

Comment: Use an old laptop PSU, they usually can provide a fair bit of current, often at 19V. Add a somewhat beefy buck converter and you should be good to go. Ideally the buck converter should be as close to the coil as possible, because the low voltages after bucking combined with a longish cable will result in a lot of voltage drop. Besides, it will allow for easier voltage adjustment on the fly. You can also make your own PWM circuit with a microcontroller (or even a 555 timer IC) and a power MOSFET, no need for smoothing if your PWM frequency is more than a couple hundred Hz.